# Events are not shown on Mixpanel dashboard after upgrading RN and Mixpanel on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, mixpanel

I've upgraded RN and Mixpanel on iOS, and everything was working fine before the upgrade. After the upgrade, there were no errors, but I can't see any events on the Dashboard. The Mixpanel Log in Xcode also looks normal. Can anyone help me figure out what else could be causing this?

Version:
react-native: 0.72.1
mixpanel-react-native: 2.3.1

Xcode Console Log:

```
[Mixpanel - Flush.swift - func flushQueueInBatches(_:type:)] (debug) - Sending batch of data
[Mixpanel - Flush.swift - func flushQueueInBatches(_:type:)] (debug) - [["$mp_metadata": {
        "mixpanel_id" = "3E3B727A-4379-408A-94BC-170436DC74E6";
            "mixpanel_id" = "3E3B727A-4379-408A-94BC-170436DC74E6";
[Mixpanel - Network.swift - func buildURLRequest(_:resource:)] (debug) - Fetching URL
[Mixpanel - Network.swift - func buildURLRequest(_:resource:)] (debug) - https://api.mixpanel.com/track/?ip=1
[Mixpanel - Flush.swift - func flushQueueInBatches(_:type:)] (debug) - Sending batch of data
[Mixpanel - MPDB.swift - func deleteRows(_:ids:isDeleteAll:)] (info) - Successfully deleted rows from table mixpanel_928bd6081524e3613b690f188f58c87a_events
[Mixpanel - Flush.swift - func flushQueueInBatches(_:type:)] (debug) - [["event": Course Bar Displayed, "id": 5908, "properties": {
[Mixpanel - Network.swift - func buildURLRequest(_:resource:)] (debug) - Fetching URL
[Mixpanel - Network.swift - func buildURLRequest(_:resource:)] (debug) - https://api.mixpanel.com/track/?ip=1
[Mixpanel - Flush.swift - func flushQueueInBatches(_:type:)] (debug) - Sending batch of data
[Mixpanel - Flush.swift - func flushQueueInBatches(_:type:)] (debug) - [["id": 5958, "$mp_metadata": {
[Mixpanel - MPDB.swift - func deleteRows(_:ids:isDeleteAll:)] (info) - Successfully deleted rows from table mixpanel_928bd6081524e3613b690f188f58c87a_events
[Mixpanel - Network.swift - func buildURLRequest(_:resource:)] (debug) - Fetching URL
[Mixpanel - Network.swift - func buildURLRequest(_:resource:)] (debug) - https://api.mixpanel.com/track/?ip=1
[Mixpanel - MPDB.swift - func deleteRows(_:ids:isDeleteAll:)] (info) - Successfully deleted rows from table mixpanel_928bd6081524e3613b690f188f58c87a_events
```